# Do I need something like CLEW to use GL-CL interop functions?

Tags: opengl, opencl

When I call clCreateFromGLBuffer, I get this crash:

> Exception thrown at 0x00000000 in App.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.

Sounds like an extension function pointer that hasn't been loaded.

Do I need something like CLEW for this?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I just needed to ensure that both OpenGL and OpenCL were running on the same platform & device.